# jQuery fluid div dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, height, fluid

This is my FLUID resposnive DIV:

```
<div class="kamil_test"></div>
```

and its for example 438px height in standard view when i resize window its for example 300px etc. everything works perfect but i need to have **width="something"** in this div

so my div in begining have to look like that

```
<div class="kamil_test" style="height: 438px;">
```

and when i resize window var inside height have to dynamicly change proportionaly to width which is 100% i need have height in **px**

when i type jquery script like this its only generate width after full render but dont refresh it.

```
$(".kamil_test").css("height", "+=0");
```

how to make it refreshable while resizeing page???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function to adjust your div size, and call when resize the window.

Ex.

```
function adjust(){
    var maxW=window.innerWidth,
    afterHeight = //your operation to obtain height,
    afterWidth = //your operation to obtain width
    $(".kamil_test").css({height:afterHeight,width:afterWidth});
}

$(document).ready(adjust);
$(window).resize(adjust);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use max-height property.

max-height/max-width will restrict the div's height/width to max of the specified value. If you specify your actual height/width relative to the parent element/Window size then it will re-size accordingly.

Try the below.

```
<div class="kamil_test" style="max-height: 438px;height: 100%;">
```